# include no RainTPL

Tags: php, include

Utilizo o RainTPL e estou tentando fazer um include em uma pagina chamando uma pagina da pasta anterior, mas nao estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, na mesma pasta funciona assim

```html
{include="cities-search"}
```

já tentei com / com ../ com ./  tentei tbm
{include=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/views/cities-search'} 
mas nenhum jeito deu certo.

Comment: E a extensão do arquivo que está incluindo? xD

Comment: é .html, mas mesmo colocando não funciona. O estranho é que o {include="cities-search"} sem a extensão e estando na mesma pasta funciona. mas no diretorio anterior nao consigo

Comment: Qual a estrutura dos diretórios aí?! Digo: onde está chamando e onde está o arquivo chamado...

Comment: O que vai ser chamado está em views e o arquivo que chama esta em views/admin

Comment: Teste aí: `include('admin/nome_do_arquivo.html');`

Comment: Template cities-search not found! - Não funcionou, mas a página que vai ser incluida esta só em views, o que esta chamando que esta no views/admin.

Comment: Agora, pela mensagem de erro, esse `include` aí está relacionado a um template do rainTPL. Talvez ele não esteja reconhecendo tal como um "template"...